# How to Use Autocomplete in Sublime Text

Tags: autocomplete

I'm switching from Dreamweaver to Sublime Text, but the way ST handles autocomplete is different from DW. In DW, the tag autocompletes when you start typing the ending tag. But with ST, it autocompletes when you type the opening tag.

My problem is that in ST, you get trapped inside the tag you're typing, and the only way to move on to the next line is to hit the right arrow key a bunch of times. That seems totally ridiculous. Is there some shortcut I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:

https://github.com/SublimeText/Tag

In my copy of ST with this plugin installed, beginning to type the end-tag completes the tag and moves the cursor to the character immediately following the end of line.

Comment: That works pretty well, except ST still auto-completes the quotes around values. Is there kind of keystroke that I'm supposed to use to get out of the tag instead of the arrow keys?

Comment: Control-f should move it past the closing quote. Control-n will take you to the next line, if that is appropriate.

Comment: ctl-f brings up the find menu, and ctl-n makes a new tab.

Comment: It looks like you just have to type the ending quote and it won't add a second one, it will just skip past the first. Kind of defeats the purpose of auto-complete though, doesn't it?

Comment: The key mappings I listed are for the Mac. I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl Enter will bring you to the next line and keep the auto complete that shows up. I'm on a mac.